# access jquery element after append function using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to get click event of the `<a>` tag using jquery when i access click event it is not accees please help.

This is my script to add data using append method

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: URL,
  data: datastring
}).done(function(data) {

  var status = JSON.parse(data);
  for (var i in status) {
    $("#loadmystatus").append(
      "<div style='float: right; margin-top: 5px;'>" +
      "<label style='font-weight: 500;' class='lblsizr'>2:45 am 02/04/2016</label>" +
      "<div class='dropdown user-menu' style='margin-right: 16px;'>" +
      "<button class='iconsiz' id='dd-user-menu' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>" +
      "<img src='image/icon/menu option.png' alt='' style='height: 6px; margin-left: 8px;'>" +
      "</button>" +
      "<div class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right' aria-labelledby='dd-user-menu'>" +
      "<a class='make dropdown-item' name='make' id='make'>" +
      "<span class='font-icon glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up'></span>" +
      "Make current status" +
      "</a>" +
      "<a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>" +
      "<span class='font-icon glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>" +
      "Remove" +
      "</a>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "<br>" +
      "<div style='border-radius: 10px;'>" +
      "<label>" + status[i].userstatus + "</label>" +
      "</div>" +
      "<hr>"
    );
  }
});
```

this is my scritp to access  tag even did nt work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#make').on('click', function(event) {
   alert("hello");
});
});
```

please help for that

Comment: `$("#loadmystatus").on('click', "#make", function(){
        alert(.....)
    });`

Comment: you can call same js file by using following function
$.getScript("Js/custom.js");
or 
you can right code in function and call it at end of you ajax response.

Comment: just FYI, with ES6 we don't need to concatenate multiline strings anymore :)

Answer (score 4):

You attach event handler to element that has not been created yet.

To solve your problem, you can attach event handler to `document` or `#loadmystatus` as Sergio suggested in the comment.

```
$(document).on('click', '#make', function(event) {
   alert("hello");
});
```

or

```
$('#loadmystatus').on('click', '#make', function(event) {
   alert("hello");
});
```

```js
$(document).on("click", "#make", function(e){alert('test')});
$("#loadmystatus").append("<button id='make'>Click me!</button>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loadmystatus"></div>
```

Comment: Instead of targeting the document I'd target `#loadmystatus`, otherwise the interpreter will have to traverse through the entire document to find the element

Comment: @SergioAlen I agree with you.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan You should not answer a basic question. There is a high possibility that its answered and you should look for it and mark it as duplicate. If you are not able to find, then its OK to answer but if then someone marks it dupe, you should remove your answer. Note, this is just my view of what I would have done.